# PyInstaller tkinter executable exits immediately on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have written a simple python tkinter programme to try PyInstaller on Mac OSX, but if I double click the executable created by PyInstaller the window closes immediately before I am able to see the GUI. Can anyone help me understand how I stop this happening?

The code is:

```
#TestGUI.py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
window = Frame(root)
window.grid()
root.title("pyInstaller Test")
label = Label(window, text="Hello World").grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

I converted it using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile TestGUI.py
```

It seemed to create the package fine but when I double click the executable a terminal window flashes open briefly but the GUI does't appear. A screen shot showed that the terminal window said:

```
$ /myDir/dist/TestGUI ; exit;
```

Does anyone know how I stop it exiting immediately? Many thanks.

Comment: This is what the console says when it happens: login: DEAD_PROCESS:

Comment: I have done a little more testing: the tkinter import statement is enough to stop this programme from working. But other programmes with import statements work fine so it seems to be a problem specific to tkinter.

Comment: Used py2app to get around this in the end.